# Adding data dynamically in AChartEngine's ZoomListener

Tags: android, achartengine

**Edit: I've looked into this further and the problem was not fundamentally caused by the code in the ZoomListener. I don't know what caused my problem, but I can confirm that the code that I posted below will run if the rest of the activity is coded correctly.**

I'm trying to create an Android activity that allows users to explore a relatively large data set using AChartEngine (think of a stock price over time at 30-second intervals for several years to get an idea of the scope). It is a bad idea to feed megabytes of data into a chart so I'm going to load and remove data dynamically whenever the user zooms or pans.

I thought a ZoomListener would be a good place to feed new data to the graph, but that causes the app to crash when the listener triggers.

Here is the simplest version of the code that crashes. (I would of course also need to run `mChartView.repaint()` to redraw the chart, but the code crashes even without that line in case you're wondering why it's not there). The mZoomedOut boolean is there to prevent the code from running over and over.

```
    mZoomListener = new ZoomListener() {
        @Override
        public void zoomApplied(ZoomEvent zoomEvent) {

            if((mRenderer.getXAxisMax()-mRenderer.getXAxisMin()) > 110){
                mZoomedOut = true;
            }

            if((mRenderer.getXAxisMax()-mRenderer.getXAxisMin()) < 100 && mZoomedOut){
                mZoomedOut = false;
                mCurrentSeries.clear();
                double x = 1;
                double y = 100;
                mCurrentSeries.add(x, y);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void zoomReset() {
        }
    };
```

Here is the resulting stack trace:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
    at org.achartengine.chart.LineChart.drawSeries(LineChart.java:168)
    at org.achartengine.chart.XYChart.drawSeries(XYChart.java:518)
    at org.achartengine.chart.XYChart.draw(XYChart.java:311)
    at org.achartengine.GraphicalView.onDraw(GraphicalView.java:168)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10978)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10417)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10380)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10380)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10380)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10380)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10380)
    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:875)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:1918)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1642)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2450)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4444)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can the ZoomListener be used to update the chart, or do I need to do it somewhere else?

Comment: Please mention the version of ACE you are using.

Comment: Hi Dan, I'm using 1.1.0. I've been making some progress today so I may end up removing my question or answering it myself in a day or two. It's possible that I just made a trivial mistake somewhere when I coded up my proof of concept.